# Reverse engineering Bluetooth LE - device sends weird responses back

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, wireshark

I recently aquired a Segway Ninebot ES2 electric scooter. I can connect to the scooter via Bluetooth LE and grab information such as battery status, current mileage, temperature, and so on. This is all done through an [application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.ninebot.ninebot&hl=en).

On my Android device, I've successfully extraceted the HCI log file, which I imported into Wireshark. I can see all the requests and commands send back and forth between my phone and the scooter. However, the requests and responses are all garbage and I have no idea how to interpret them.

**Example of a sent command** (info says `Sent Write Command, Handle: 0x000e (Nordic UART Service: Nordic UART Tx)`)

[image: sent command]

**Example of the received value I got right after** (info says `Rcvd Handle Value Notification, Handle: 0x000b (Nordic UART Service: Nordic UART Rx)`)

[image: received]

How am I supposed to interpret these responses? If the battery status was 59%, I would expect it to return something like `0x3b` (0x3b hex is 59 decimal). But honestly, I have no idea how this works. Maybe they're returning a bunch of data in a data type only their app knows how to interpret? Like JSON for web.

Here's an example from the [nRF Connect for Mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=en) application, where I hit the down arrow on all the characteristics: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1O3F2.jpg (large image)

And probably more important: How do I replicate a request or command in nRF Connect? I've tried sending a byte array that looks like `0x {02410011000d.....}` (from the Write Command) in the application, but I have no idea how to read the response.

Comment: hi @MortenMoulder, could you please share with me the example project to connect to the Segway Ninebot ES2 electric scooter. I also recently acquired one and I am making an android lab app, but it has been difficult for me to connect and communicate with it programmatically.

Comment: @devjav Never got it to work. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

If someone is still interested, I did the same research for this scooter.

That's standart BLE communacation, device offers BLE "services" and "characteristics". Service can contain one or more characteristics, by which you communicate with device. Each charateristic can allow different types of interaction with it: writing into it, reading from it, subscribing to notifications (so you dont have to to manually read, it kinda pushes data to your app), and more (read [here](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/nordic/short-range-guides/b/bluetooth-low-energy/posts/ble-characteristics-a-beginners-tutorial), for example)

Take a look at your wireshark screenshot: you can see Service UUID, Handle UUID (the characteristic), and handle ID. You can communicate with device via uuid or id, depending on your programming language or library ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656306/understanding-long-and-short-form-of-uuid) about uuids).

In this particular scooter there are two characteristics, one allows writing into it, another - allows subscribing to it. Together, they act like RX and TX wires in UART: you write data into one and read from another. So, to begin communication with scooter you must establish connection to it, subscribe for notifications from one ch, and write data to another.

As for protocol: look again at she screenshots, "UART Tx" is the actual payload that was sent to scooter and "UART Rx" was the response. Yes, it's binary data, that only app would understand. Luckily, protocol has been reverse engineered and is well [documented](https://github.com/etransport/ninebot-docs/wiki/protocol). In your example app requests serial number, and it's returned in response - "N2GWX...". In order to request battery percentage you must build another payload according to protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's still relevant, but at least for those, who will be interested in the topic.

You can try the following to understand how to interpret response from the device.

An option to consider is to fetch manufacturer's mobile app (apk) either by adb or from sites like apkmirror, etc.
Then apply some reverse-eng tool like JADX.
If you're lucky and the code is somewhat readable, then search for smth that has to do with response (like ResponseParser) and try to find algo that is used to interpret the response.

However, the very first attemp should always be to search on github/google if smb did it already for your device, unless it's very niche.